# DRF - Serializer fields "source" argument unclear behaviour

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, consider the following:

```
>>> d = {'macAddress': '00:00:00:00:00:00'}
>>> s = DeviceSerializer(data=d)
>>> s
DeviceSerializer(data={'macAddress':'00:00:00:00:00:00'}):
    mac_address = CharField(max_length=20, source='macAddress')
>>> s.is_valid()
False
>>> s.errors
{'mac_address': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

Based on the simple above example and my current understanding of the `source` field argument I would expect the `mac_address` field to be automatically mapped to the `macAddress` in the input data and the serializer to be valid.

Why this is not the case?

Thanks to anyone willing to help out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the other way around. `source` is what is on the python side and the field name on the external/API side.

```
data = {'mac_address':'00:00:00:00:00:00'}
```

would lead to:

```
validated_data == {'macAddress':'00:00:00:00:00:00'}
```

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you a lot sir.